# How to let ee editor syntax highlight?

Tags: freebsd

Does anyone know how to let ee editor can syntax highlight ?

I see the setting it seems no syntax highlight function , but vi or vim is too complicate for me ...

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ee does not support syntax highlighting. You may want to have a  look at nano (from the ports collection editors/nano) which is a easy to use editor with syntax highlighting.

for more information on nano syntax highlighting see https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/syntax-highlighting-on-nano

Answer (score 1):

You may use Emacs as a console text editor too, you could install it with Ports

editors/emacs or without X11 interface (for servers), highly lighter, port : editors/emacs-nox11

Emacs use the the same bindings than your prefered shell, bash or ZSh, in fact shells use the same binding than emacs.

Emacs is more like ee or nano, about keyboards shortcut, but much more powerfull and configurable, scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider to use nano you might want to create a file .nanorc in your user directory or in /usr/local/etc/nanorc for all user containing this in:

```
    ## Nanorc files
include "/usr/local/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc"
## C/C++
include "/usr/local/share/nano/c.nanorc"
## HTML
include "/usr/local/share/nano/html.nanorc"
## TeX
include "/usr/local/share/nano/tex.nanorc"
## Quoted emails (under e.g. mutt)
include "/usr/local/share/nano/mutt.nanorc"
## Patch files
include "/usr/local/share/nano/patch.nanorc"
## Manpages
include "/usr/local/share/nano/man.nanorc"
## Groff
include "/usr/local/share/nano/groff.nanorc"
## Perl
include "/usr/local/share/nano/perl.nanorc"
## Python
include "/usr/local/share/nano/python.nanorc"
## Ruby
include "/usr/local/share/nano/ruby.nanorc"
## Java
include "/usr/local/share/nano/java.nanorc"
## Assembler
include "/usr/local/share/nano/asm.nanorc"
## Bourne shell scripts
include "/usr/local/share/nano/sh.nanorc"
## POV-Ray
include "/usr/local/share/nano/pov.nanorc"
```